# Mixing C and Objective-C and effects

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I am new to Objective-C and I am wondering if it is possible to mix C and pure Objective-C freely. If so, does it have any effects on my program?

Comment: From what I heard, I think you can

Comment: Objective-C is a strict superset of C. All Objective-C code is C code.

Comment: It's the other way around: all C code is Objective-C code.  `[super viewDidLoad]` is not C code.

Comment: So for an iphone app i can mix both C and objective C ?

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is a strict superset of C thus C code is a subset of Objective-C code so all C code is also Objective-C code.

Thus you can include any C code in Objective-C.